# Django view processing too slow

Tags: json, django, ajax

In my Django App I have a view that takes too much time to deliver and I can’t realize exactly why. Maybe there is a way to optimize this process.

**The scheme**

I load a page regularly with View 1 and when that page is ready $(document).ready(function() I load a Json with the rest of the data via AJAX from View 2.

That View 2 is taking too much to deliver the result although we are talking of only around 180 queryset lines.

Even more, I have server cache setup so the actual database is not consulted.

Both server cache and general app server works fine, the rest of my app’s views deliver results in low times. You can check: [www.kinemed.com.ar](http://www.kinemed.com.ar)

**The AJAX call**

I guess the problem isn’t here, but just in case.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/website/some/',
        type:'GET',
        data: {},
        success:function(data){
            window.data = JSON.parse(data);
            makeMenu(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('something went wrong here');
        },
    });
 });
```

**The View 2**

As you can see. The “Productos” queryset is loaded from cache, but event If it wasn’t, the amount of data is low.

The full “ProductosBase” model hast around 600 items and after filtering we get only around 180 items.

```
@transaction.atomic
def ShopSegundoPlanoView(request):

    productos = cache.get("productos_argentina")
    if not productos:
        productos = ProductosBase.objects.filter(venta_arge_ok=True)
        cache.set("productos_argentina", productos)

    productos_shop = productos.exclude(foto_1=None).exclude(foto_1='').exclude(foto_2=None).exclude(foto_2='').order_by(
        'marca', 'producto', 'packaging')

    array_productos_shop = []

    for x in productos_shop:

        uds_en_orden = 0
        subtotal_en_orden = 0

        if x.colecciones.all():
            colecciones = str(x.colecciones.all())
        else:
            colecciones = ''

        to_add = {
            'id': x.id,
            'producto': x.producto,
            'packaging': x.packaging,
            'marca': x.marca.marca,
            "color": x.color_link.img_color.url,
            "color_nombre": x.color_link.color,
            "precio": x.precio_lista,
            "medida": str(x.ancho) + ' ' + str(x.medida_ancho) + ' x ' + str(x.largo) + ' ' + str(x.medida_largo),
            "compra_minima": x.pedido_minimo,
            "categoria": x.categoria_producto.categoria_producto,
            "colecciones": colecciones,
            "imagen": x.foto_1.url,
            "imagen_2": x.foto_2.url,
            "uds_en_orden": uds_en_orden,
            "subtotal_en_orden": subtotal_en_orden,
            "descripcion": x.descripcion,
            "usos": x.categoria_producto.usos,
        }

        array_productos_shop.append(to_add)

array_productos_shop = json.dumps(array_productos_shop, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
data = {'array_productos_shop': array_productos_shop}

return JsonResponse(data)
```

I imagine that the time is consumed in the iteration to generate the results array, but once again I guess it shouldn’t take that much to process.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

As William sugested I changed my query to prefetch foreign fields and even include that in the cache.

```
    productos_shop = cache.get("productos_argentina_shop")
    if not productos_shop:
        productos_shop = ProductosBase.objects.filter(venta_arge_ok=True).exclude(Q(foto_1=None) | Q(foto_1='') | Q(foto_2=None) | Q(foto_2='')).select_related('categoria_producto', 'marca', 'color_link').prefetch_related('colecciones').order_by('marca', 'producto', 'packaging')
        cache.set("productos_argentina_shop", productos_shop)
```

The result was that my response lowered from 30 to 25 seconds. Still I think it has no sense to tale so much time to deliver the json. The result is only 180 records and 400k.

There must be something else that's affecting this? I don't have this performance problem in other views of the same app.

Here you can see the timing of the response.

[image]

**UPDATE II**

I measured server side process with Server Timing API.

The block where I get the queryset takes only 54ms. That seems right.

The forloop block takes 25 second for 180 elements. Around 140 ms per iteration. Is that amount reasonable? I'm not an expert on this but it sounds quite slow.

**The model**

```
class ProductosBase(models.Model):
codigo_kinemed = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Código de profucto Kinemed", blank=True, null=True)
codigo_barra = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Código de barras", blank=True, null=True)
codigo_inner = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Código de barras", blank=True, null=True)
codigo_master = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Código de barras", blank=True, null=True)
item_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Item number", blank=True, null=True)
marca = models.ForeignKey("Marcas", help_text="Marca", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
categoria_producto = models.ForeignKey("Categorias_Producto", help_text="Categorias de producto", blank=True,
                                       null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
sub_categoria_producto = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Categorias_Producto, help_text="", blank=True, null=True,
                                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
producto = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Producto", blank=True, null=True)
producto_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Producto", default="", blank=True, null=True)
color = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Color", blank=True, null=True)
color_ing = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Color", blank=True, null=True)
color_link = models.ForeignKey(ColorBase, help_text="Marca", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

CMS = "cm"
MTS = "mt"
MMS = "mm"
medidas_CHOICES = ((CMS, 'cm'), (MTS, 'mt'), (MMS, 'mm'),)

ancho = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del ancho", blank=True, null=True)
medida_ancho = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=medidas_CHOICES, default=CMS, help_text="Tipo",)

largo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, help_text="Largo en mts", blank=True, null=True)
medida_largo = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=medidas_CHOICES, default=MTS, help_text="Tipo",)

packaging = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Formato de packaging", blank=True, null=True)
pedido_minimo = models.IntegerField(help_text="Pedido Mínimo", blank=True, null=True)
units_inner = models.IntegerField(help_text="Units por Inner box", blank=True, null=True)
inner_master = models.IntegerField(help_text="Inner boxes por Master box", blank=True, null=True)
caja_venta_arg = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
tier = models.IntegerField(help_text="Master boxes por nivel de pallet", blank=True, null=True)
descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=500, help_text="Descripción del producto", blank=True)
foto_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="", blank=True, null=True)
foto_1_M = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="", blank=True, null=True)
foto_1_L = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="", blank=True, null=True)
foto_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="", blank=True, null=True)
foto_2_M = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="", blank=True, null=True)
foto_2_L = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="", blank=True, null=True)
video_link = models.URLField("Video link", max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
estatus_contenido = models.ForeignKey("WorkflowContenidos", help_text="Estatus del contenido", blank=True,
                                      null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
priority = models.IntegerField(help_text="Prioridad para mostrar", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
priority_web = models.IntegerField(help_text="Prioridad para mostrar", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
precio_lista = models.IntegerField(help_text="Precio de lista", blank=True, null=True)
precio_pvp = models.IntegerField(help_text="PVP sugerido", blank=True, null=True)
region = models.ForeignKey("ListasRegionales", help_text="Lista regional", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
lista_nicho = models.ForeignKey("ListasNicho", help_text="Lista nicho", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
producto_ing = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre en inglés", blank=True, null=True)
packaging_ing = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Packaging inglés", blank=True, null=True)
uom = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="UOM", blank=True, null=True)
precio_compra = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del ancho", blank=True, null=True)
precio_por = models.ForeignKey("PrecioPor", help_text="Lista nicho", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
precio_lista_internacional = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del ancho", blank=True, null=True)
precio_lista_internacional_B = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del ancho", blank=True, null=True)
total_vendidas = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
media_ventas_mes = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
ventas_ultimo_mes = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
existencias = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
existencias_bloqueada = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
duracion_stock = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
estatus_reposicion = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre en inglés", blank=True, null=True)
made_in = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Nombre producto", blank=False, null=True)
nombre_zetti = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="max 30 char", blank=True, null=True)
nombre_anmat = models.ForeignKey("CertificadoPM", help_text="Marca", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
peso_master_box = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del ancho", blank=True, null=True)
page = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
cuenta = models.IntegerField(help_text="Total ventas historicas", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
descuento_max = models.IntegerField(help_text="Descuento max", default=0, blank=True, null=True)
venta_arge_ok = models.BooleanField(default=False)
venta_inte_ok = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_father = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_mother = models.BooleanField(default=False)
largo_master_box = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del largo", blank=True, null=True)
ancho_master_box = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del ancho", blank=True, null=True)
alto_master_box = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del alto", blank=True, null=True)
ratio_importacion = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Valor del alto", blank=True, null=True)
pos_arancelaria = models.ForeignKey("PosicionArancelaria", help_text="Marca", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image_gallery = models.ManyToManyField('stockbucket.ImageGalery', related_name='image_gallery', blank=True, help_text="")
colecciones = models.ManyToManyField('Colecciones', related_name='Colecciones', blank=True, help_text="")
```

**Print connections**

As suggested by William I tested:

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries)
```

With this result

```
[{'sql': 'BEGIN', 'time': '0.000'}, {'sql': 'SELECT "catalog_productosbase"."id", "catalog_productosbase"."codigo_kinemed", "catalog_productosbase"."codigo_barra", "catalog_productosbase"."codigo_inner", "catalog_productosbase"."codigo_master", "catalog_productosbase"."item_number", "catalog_productosbase"."marca_id", "catalog_productosbase"."categoria_producto_id", "catalog_productosbase"."sub_categoria_producto_id", "catalog_productosbase"."producto", "catalog_productosbase"."producto_apellido", "catalog_productosbase"."color", "catalog_productosbase"."color_ing", "catalog_productosbase"."color_link_id", "catalog_productosbase"."ancho", "catalog_productosbase"."medida_ancho", "catalog_productosbase"."largo", "catalog_productosbase"."medida_largo", "catalog_productosbase"."packaging", "catalog_productosbase"."pedido_minimo", "catalog_productosbase"."units_inner", "catalog_productosbase"."inner_master", "catalog_productosbase"."caja_venta_arg", "catalog_productosbase"."tier", "catalog_productosbase"."descripcion", "catalog_productosbase"."foto_1", "catalog_productosbase"."foto_1_M", "catalog_productosbase"."foto_1_L", "catalog_productosbase"."foto_2", "catalog_productosbase"."foto_2_M", "catalog_productosbase"."foto_2_L", "catalog_productosbase"."video_link", "catalog_productosbase"."estatus_contenido_id", "catalog_productosbase"."priority", "catalog_productosbase"."priority_web", "catalog_productosbase"."precio_lista", "catalog_productosbase"."precio_pvp", "catalog_productosbase"."region_id", "catalog_productosbase"."lista_nicho_id", "catalog_productosbase"."producto_ing", "catalog_productosbase"."packaging_ing", "catalog_productosbase"."uom", "catalog_productosbase"."precio_compra", "catalog_productosbase"."precio_por_id", "catalog_productosbase"."precio_lista_internacional", "catalog_productosbase"."precio_lista_internacional_B", "catalog_productosbase"."total_vendidas", "catalog_productosbase"."media_ventas_mes", "catalog_productosbase"."ventas_ultimo_mes", "catalog_productosbase"."existencias", "catalog_productosbase"."existencias_bloqueada", "catalog_productosbase"."duracion_stock", "catalog_productosbase"."estatus_reposicion", "catalog_productosbase"."made_in", "catalog_productosbase"."nombre_zetti", "catalog_productosbase"."nombre_anmat_id", "catalog_productosbase"."peso_master_box", "catalog_productosbase"."page", "catalog_productosbase"."cuenta", "catalog_productosbase"."descuento_max", "catalog_productosbase"."venta_arge_ok", "catalog_productosbase"."venta_inte_ok", "catalog_productosbase"."is_father", "catalog_productosbase"."is_mother", "catalog_productosbase"."largo_master_box", "catalog_productosbase"."ancho_master_box", "catalog_productosbase"."alto_master_box", "catalog_productosbase"."ratio_importacion", "catalog_productosbase"."pos_arancelaria_id", "catalog_marcas"."id", "catalog_marcas"."marca", "catalog_marcas"."slug", "catalog_marcas"."marca_anmat", "catalog_marcas"."descripcion_brief", "catalog_marcas"."descripcion_long", "catalog_marcas"."logo", "catalog_marcas"."logo_full", "catalog_marcas"."logo_transparente", "catalog_marcas"."foto_1", "catalog_marcas"."brand_video", "catalog_marcas"."web", "catalog_marcas"."pais", "catalog_marcas"."pais_origen_productos", "catalog_marcas"."orden_lista", "catalog_marcas"."tiempo_entrega", "catalog_marcas"."modalidad_compra_id", "catalog_marcas"."venta_arge_ok", "catalog_categorias_producto"."id", "catalog_categorias_producto"."categoria_producto", "catalog_categorias_producto"."slug", "catalog_categorias_producto"."categoria_producto_ing", "catalog_categorias_producto"."descripcion_brief", "catalog_categorias_producto"."descripcion_long", "catalog_categorias_producto"."usos", "catalog_categorias_producto"."foto_1", "catalog_categorias_producto"."foto_2", "catalog_categorias_producto"."foto_1_M", "catalog_categorias_producto"."foto_2_M", "catalog_categorias_producto"."video", "catalog_categorias_producto"."perfil_cliente", "catalog_categorias_producto"."estatus_contenido_id", "catalog_categorias_producto"."orden_lista", "catalog_categorias_producto"."orden_marca", "catalog_categorias_producto"."venta_arge_ok", "catalog_colorbase"."id", "catalog_colorbase"."color", "catalog_colorbase"."color_ing", "catalog_colorbase"."img_color", "catalog_colorbase"."priority" FROM "catalog_productosbase" LEFT OUTER JOIN "catalog_marcas" ON ("catalog_productosbase"."marca_id" = "catalog_marcas"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "catalog_categorias_producto" ON ("catalog_productosbase"."categoria_producto_id" = "catalog_categorias_producto"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "catalog_colorbase" ON ("catalog_productosbase"."color_link_id" = "catalog_colorbase"."id") WHERE ("catalog_productosbase"."venta_arge_ok" = 1 AND NOT (("catalog_productosbase"."foto_1" IS NULL OR ("catalog_productosbase"."foto_1" = \'\' AND "catalog_productosbase"."foto_1" IS NOT NULL) OR "catalog_productosbase"."foto_2" IS NULL OR ("catalog_productosbase"."foto_2" = \'\' AND "catalog_productosbase"."foto_2" IS NOT NULL)))) ORDER BY "catalog_productosbase"."marca_id" ASC, "catalog_productosbase"."producto" ASC, "catalog_productosbase"."packaging" ASC', 'time': '0.015'}, {'sql': 'SELECT ("catalog_productosbase_colecciones"."productosbase_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_productosbase_id", "catalog_colecciones"."id", "catalog_colecciones"."nombre", "catalog_colecciones"."prioridad", "catalog_colecciones"."short_text", "catalog_colecciones"."perfil_cliente" FROM "catalog_colecciones" INNER JOIN "catalog_productosbase_colecciones" ON ("catalog_colecciones"."id" = "catalog_productosbase_colecciones"."colecciones_id") WHERE "catalog_productosbase_colecciones"."productosbase_id" IN (78, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 11, 13, 14, 133, 16, 135, 18, 19, 20, 100, 101, 102, 130, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 99, 84, 85, 148, 88, 89, 520, 86, 87, 22, 140, 141, 424, 425, 426, 427, 372, 373, 523, 524, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 150, 151, 175, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 122, 123, 126, 127, 128, 129, 160, 161, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 250, 251, 39, 41, 124, 125, 154, 155, 222, 343, 177, 178, 179, 143, 428, 429, 431, 79, 43, 44, 45, 46, 432, 437, 47, 48, 49, 268, 264, 77, 65, 72, 73, 61, 62, 63, 64, 71, 69, 70, 67, 68, 66, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 95, 96, 97, 98, 233, 234, 91, 92, 93, 94, 235, 241, 353, 356, 354, 355, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 412, 413, 406, 408, 423, 409, 410, 411, 414, 417, 637, 612, 634, 633, 636) ORDER BY "catalog_colecciones"."prioridad" ASC', 'time': '0.000'}]
```

**UPDATE III**

I used nplusone package as William suggested and got rid of n+1 and egaer alerts. So that issue should be optimized.

But it still takes 25 seconds to process the forloop. Around 140 ms per iteration.

**UPDATE IV**

I found that from thhos 25 seconds, 17.5 are related to the image fields:

```
"imagen": x.foto_1.url,
"imagen_2": x.foto_2.url,
```

I guess there is something related to that.

Comment: The problem is that you have an *N+1 problem*, the `x.colecciones.all()` will each time make an extra query.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I took the x.colecciones.all() part of the code and it still takes the same time to process

Comment: yes, since `categoria_producto`, `marca` and `color_link` are likely also N+1 problems (as well as perhaps some others). Every item where you follow a ForeignKey or m2m relation will result in extra queries.

Comment: the solution is not to take it out of the loop, but use `.select_related` and `.prefetch_related` to load objects more efficient.

Comment: @FranciscoGhlfi: you can try to find other N+1 problems with https://github.com/jmcarp/nplusone the point is that you need to perform `.select_related(..)` on all one-to-one and foreignkey fields, and `.prefetch_related` on all reversed foreign keys and many-to-many fields.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated the info UPDATE II

Comment: well this makes perfect sense, since as said before, if you do not `.prefetch_related` and `.select_related` properly it will make *queries in the `for` loop*. This is why the *N+1 problem* is so severe: because the number of roundtrips to the database scales *linear* with the data. As said before you should look what `ForeignKey`s, `ManyToManyField`s, etc. you access, and move these to the `.select_related` and `.prefetch_related` clauses in the query to fetch related objects *in bulk*.

Comment: I already did that, look at the Update I.

Comment: you copied it, but likely there are still *other* `ForeignKey`s. Please share the models...

Comment: for example `categoria_producto` is probably also an FK? Then you should add it to the `.select_related` clause... Likely now the time/iteration will drop with ~40ms

Comment: There I added the model's code. But I see no other fileds that were not included. categoria_producto is already in the .select_related.

Comment: well the github.com/jmcarp/nplusone can detect most N+1 problems automatically, it also shows this in a graphical way. So that might help to identify cases.

Comment: alternatively you can use `from django.db import connection; print(connection.queries)` to print the queries it makes and look for patterns yourself (which is basically what the package does). The point is that nothing in the loop should take that long. But queries to the database, these take that long.

Comment: Are you sure it takes the new queryset, and does not take some cached one (without prefetches, etc.)? Are you sure you *iterate* over this queryset, and not the old one?

Comment: I'll try your suggestions. Meanwhile, yes I'm sure the cahe version is ok. If I flush the cache the block where I load the queryset it takes 250ms, from cache takes 54ms

Comment: Added the print(connection.queries) result to the post. As far as I understand there is only 1 sql call right?

Comment: no *two* queries one that selects the `Productos` with the `ForeignKey`s, and one per many-to-many field that is loaded with `.prefetch_related(..)`, this is done to avoid bandwidth usage. You should however look for patterns where almost the same query is performed multiple times (like ~100x) since that means it performs queries in the `for` loop, and that is undesirable, since that means the number of queries will grow quite large.

Comment: Did you write the printing of the queries at the *bottom* of the `for` loop? So after the (entire) `for` loop ran? (just before returing the result)?

Comment: Just before the Json retun. At the very end of the view

Comment: I tryied the nplusone but I have a problem. The main page loads ok but the ajax call gets 500 error

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did UPDATE III

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason behind the slow process.

Williams suggestions helped optimize the database query to avoid n+1 problems. But the main issue was in the image.url fields.

Although they are not detected as n+1, I think they behave like one due to the fact that url is not actually a value in the database but a property.

What I understand is that another call is made on those fields.

As I'm using Google Cloud Storage for Media, I guess that interaction is what takes time to gather the URL property from the image field.

I workaround that using cahe server to store the processed view.

```
@timed_wrapper('ShopSegundoPlanoView', 'Json load')
@transaction.atomic

def ShopSegundoPlanoView(request):

json_timmer = TimedService('first', 'Json load')
json_timmer.start()

array_productos_shop = cache.get("productos_argentina_shop")
if not array_productos_shop:
    productos_shop = ProductosBase.objects.filter(venta_arge_ok=True).exclude(Q(foto_1=None) | Q(foto_1='') | Q(foto_2=None) | Q(foto_2='')).select_related('categoria_producto', 'marca', 'color_link').prefetch_related('colecciones').order_by('marca', 'producto', 'packaging')

    array_productos_shop = []

    for x in productos_shop:

        uds_en_orden = 0
        subtotal_en_orden = 0

        if x.colecciones.all().exists():
            colecciones = str(x.colecciones.all())
            print(colecciones)
        else:
            colecciones = ''

        to_add = {
            'id': x.id,
            'producto': x.producto,
            'packaging': x.packaging,
            'marca': x.marca.marca,
            "color": x.color_link.img_color.url,
            "color_nombre": x.color_link.color,
            "precio": x.precio_lista,
            "medida": str(x.ancho) + ' ' + str(x.medida_ancho) + ' x ' + str(x.largo) + ' ' + str(x.medida_largo),
            "compra_minima": x.pedido_minimo,
            "categoria": x.categoria_producto.categoria_producto,
            "colecciones": colecciones,
            "imagen": x.foto_1.url,
            "imagen_2": x.foto_2.url,
            "uds_en_orden": uds_en_orden,
            "subtotal_en_orden": subtotal_en_orden,
            "descripcion": x.descripcion,
            "usos": x.categoria_producto.usos,
        }

        array_productos_shop.append(to_add)

    array_productos_shop = json.dumps(array_productos_shop, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    array_productos_shop = {'array_productos_shop': array_productos_shop}
    cache.set("productos_argentina_shop", array_productos_shop)
    json_timmer.end()

return JsonResponse(array_productos_shop)
```